# Options for Java POJO dirty tracking?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I have a MongoDB Spring Repo that I want to do patching with to minimize update sizes. In order to do so, I need to track which properties have been modified. Essentially something like:

```
class MyPojo {
   Set<String> dirtyProperties;
   int i;

   void setI(int i) {
     this.i = i;
     dirtyProperties.add("I");
   }
}
```

But I don't want to have to implement `.add()` in every class for every property.

From my research:

- AOP / AspectJ: only works on beans? Pojos from the Spring Repo aren't going to be beans
- ByteBuddy interceptor / Dynamic Proxy on set methods and when I get a Pojo from the Spring repo, I'd have to create the proxy class for every pojo?
- is there a way to customize what Lombok `@Data` does?
- any other options?

I'd ideally like some kind of solution like `@Data` where I can annotate a class and have it generate the code like Lombok does. I.e. something self contained.

Comment: As far as I know, AOP / AspectJ is dead and has been for quite some time.  No one uses it anymore.

Comment: And I think Dynamic Proxies only work on interfaces.  For each POJO, you'd need an interface you can attach the proxy to.

Comment: The solution is AspectJ, which is definitely not dead and always updated to understand the latest Java byte code versions. E.g., AspectJ 1.9.9.1 supports Java 18. Java 19 is supported in a development version which would have been released right after the Java 19 release, if the Eclipse Java Compiler (which is part of AspectJ in a forked version) would finally add the rest of its incomplete Java 19 preview feature support for which I opened several tickets. AJ is fully supported by Spring, but also works without Spring, because it is an independent project older than Spring.

Comment: AspectJ does not need any proxies (AspectJ != Spring AOP, the latter is only "AOP lite") and can intercept both your setter methods or even property read/write access, if necessary. Optionally, you can even avoid to add `Set<String> dirtyProperties` to your POJO classes, if you use a non-singleton aspect instantiation model like `perthis` or `pertarget` and do the book-keeping inside the aspect, fully encapsulating the cross-cutting concern there. In order to propose a concrete solution, I need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing how/where you use the "dirty" property.

Comment: @kriegaex yeah, I kind of have it partially working with AspectJ. Basically, a mongo patch operation is to copy only the changed properties into an Update object (which is a dictionary). So in the example above, the Update object would contain "i": 5, so you need to track which properties are dirty and copy the property name and value over to the Update object.

Comment: In order to make your question more useful for the Stack Overflow community and also to get you from "partially working" to a full solution, please do add your MCVE and, if you can fully solve the problem by yourself, present a comprehensive solution here as an answer or otherwise let me help you.