# AspectJ member introduction doesn't build

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj

I have a POJO:

```java
class Test {
  private int i;
  void setI(int i) {
    this.i = i;
  }
}
```

this is what I have so far for the aspect:

```java
public aspect t perthis(within(@Tracking *)){

  private Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

  pointcut setterMethod() : execution(public void set*(..));

  after(Object o) returning() : setterMethod() && this(o) {
    set.add(thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    System.out.println(set);
  }

  public Set<String> go() {
    return set;
  }
}
```

I want a `Set<String> set` for any instance of ANY class that has @Tracking. I also want to add the go() method for any instance of ANY class that has @Tracking.

Can't figure out the syntax. The go() method doesn't get added. If I put Test.go() then the method get added, but then it crashes during runtime.

Comment: This is an obvious follow-up question of [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74332302/1082681). Why did you not follow my advice there to edit the original question to be an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This way, the other question is still open and has no answer. Anyway, here I have something to work with. But please, show the log of your runtime error and mention the AspectJ version and Java version. Please also explain how you build.

Comment: @kriegaex the runtime crash I figured out. I needed to add `spring.aop.auto=false`. I also got the `perthis` scope working. So the issue now is just how to get the `go()` method to be able to reference `set` and attach to ANY class.  If I change it to `Test.go()` it attaches to the `Test` class, but as a static method and can no longer access `set` in the aspect. If I leave it as just `go()` it can access `set`, but obviously not added to the `Test` class.

Comment: I have a simple solution in mind which does not even need `per*` instantiation, but am still working in my daytime job. Gonna reply later. Stay tuned. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Marker interface:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.tracking;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(TYPE)
public @interface Track {}
```

**Sample POJOs with/without marker annotation:**

We use two sample classes for positive/negative tests.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import de.scrum_master.tracking.Track;

@Track
class TestTracked {
  private int number;
  private String text;

  public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
  }

  public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "TestTracked [number=" + number + ", text=" + text + "]";
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

class TestUntracked {
  private int number;
  private String text;

  public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
  }

  public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "TestUntracked [number=" + number + ", text=" + text + "]";
  }
}
```

**"Dirty tracker" interface:**

We want the aspect to implement the following interface for each class annotated by `@Track` by means of inter-type declaration (ITD).

```java
package de.scrum_master.tracking;

import java.util.Set;

public interface Trackable {
  Set<String> getDirty();
}
```

**Driver application:**

Here, we are assuming that each POJO class annotated with the marker interface automagically implements the `Trackable` interface and therefore knows the `getDirty()` method, which the we call in order to verify that the aspect correctly tracks setter calls.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import de.scrum_master.tracking.Trackable;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestTracked testTracked = new TestTracked();
    testTracked.setNumber(11);
    testTracked.setText("foo");
    System.out.println(testTracked);
    if (testTracked instanceof Trackable)
      System.out.println("Dirty members: " + ((Trackable) testTracked).getDirty());

    TestUntracked testUntracked = new TestUntracked();
    testUntracked.setNumber(22);
    testUntracked.setText("bar");
    System.out.println(testUntracked);
    if (testUntracked instanceof Trackable)
      System.out.println("Dirty members: " + ((Trackable) testUntracked).getDirty());
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

This aspect makes each `@Track`-annotated class implement interface `Trackable` and provides both a private field storing tracking information and a `getDirty()` method implementation returning its value. Furthermore, the aspect makes sure to store the "dirty" information for each successfully executed setter.

```java
package de.scrum_master.tracking;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public aspect TrackingAspect {
  private Set<String> Trackable.dirty = new HashSet<>();

  public Set<String> Trackable.getDirty() {
    return dirty;
  }

  declare parents : @Track * implements Trackable;

  pointcut setterMethod() : execution(public void set*(..));

  after(Trackable trackable) returning() : setterMethod() && this(trackable) {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    trackable.dirty.add(thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName().substring(3));
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

You will see this when running the driver application:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.TestTracked.setNumber(int))
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.TestTracked.setText(String))
TestTracked [number=11, text=foo]
Dirty members: [Number, Text]
TestUntracked [number=22, text=bar]
```

The reason why we do not need `perthis` or `pertarget` instantiation is that we store the "dirty" information right inside the original classes. Alternatively, we could use `per*` instantiation and keep all information inside the corresponding aspect instances instead of using ITD. In that case however, the "dirty" information would be unaccessible from outside the aspect, which might even be desirable with regard to encapsulation. But then, whatever action needs to be performed when storing the "dirty" instances, would also need to happen from inside the aspect. As you did not provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and hence your question is lacking detail, I did not consider this functionality in the aspect. I can easily imagine how this could be done with both aspect variants - `per*` instantiation vs. ITD - but I hate to speculate and then be wrong.

Comment: The "use of the dirty data" is out of scope for the question -- that's a MongoDB thing, I just need the dirty set. I did actually get a similar partial solution to what you're proposing with weaving the interface into the classes. The thing I didn't like about it was that you had to typecast the class to the interface to call the new woven method(s) where as the code I posted in the question weaves it into the class directly (although wasn't able to get the `getDirty()` method working) and Intellij recognizes it. There's no way to weave a instance method in? :(

Comment: Might almost be better to use a base class for all the POJO and just use AspectJ for the setter hooks :(

Comment: was kind of hoping there was something like `public Set<String> (*.).go()` :)

Comment: No, you do not need to typecast. I just did in order to avoid squiggly lines in the editor of my IDE and in order to make it clearer to you what I was doing. But it also compiles without the cast. I did not know how generic you wish the solution to be, so I added the `if (xyz instanceof Trackable)` in order to show you how you can make it work even in places where you handle a mixture of ITD-enhanced code and normal code not implementing the interface.

Comment: I think I solved your problem, what is bad about it? Some people find a solution for every problem, while others find a problem in every solution. Like I said, if you do not need to access the dirty set from outside the aspect, you do not even need ITD, a `per*` aspect would be enough. But if you do wish to add fields and/or getters to the target classes, there is no other way than to either declare it for every single class or to use the trick with the implemented interface. It is quite simple, and you do not need to change your target classes at all - very clean. What is the problem?

Comment: woah, I am not bashing your effort or answer or anything. I just hoped the solution would be "cleaner". It is definitely clean on capturing the setters. Just the `((Trackable) testTracked).getDirty()` is a little less cleaner then I have hoped. If you do have a `Set<String> Test.dirtyProperties()` in the aspect then it injects it into the class without the need for typecasting, but then it only works for that one class and I hadn't figured out how to return the set. I was simply asking if there was a way to use that method more generically, if not then the typecasting thing is fine.

Comment: Like I said, there is no need to typecast, the AspectJ compiler will handle it just fine, just imperfect IDE plugins for Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA might show "errors" in the editor. OTOH, the casts also make the code more readable here, because they document your intent. Otherwise your co-developers who are not so aspect-savvy might get confused, not seeing the target method anywhere in the class. If they follow the trail laid by the cast to the interface, they will also find the corresponding aspect and hopefully understand better what you are doing here. But it is up to you to (not) cast.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I'm using LTW because CTW has a lot of other annoyances :) so I have to cast. Guess I was hoping for something slick like Lombok @Data, but Lombok closed that door too.

Comment: If your data class was immutable, you could just use a Java record instead of `@Data`. BTW, what annoys you about CTW?

Comment: When I was changing stuff around for POC, I'd often have to do a full project rebuild. I did have the aspectj-maven-plugin in my pom, but it seemed like it wasn't trigger sometimes and the app would crash on startup and a rebuild would fix it.

Comment: Not sure of the exact sequence of events that would force me to do a full rebuild, and I assume once you get the aspect stable, it wouldn't... but it seems like intellij didn't build the .aj file on occasion.